# How to make two or more different font files use a common Atlas in libgdx?

Tags: libgdx

I use different fonts for different screens. some of the fonts are only few letters, so it would be inefficient to generate an atlas for each font.So is there a way to make all of my fonts use a single Atlas?

Comment: Are you using the LibGDX TexturePacker? You can simply drop bitmap font images into the source directory that gets packed. You can instantiate the BitmapFont by passing in the associated TextureRegion from your TextureAtlas rather than passing it a Texture.

Comment: I am using Hiero to generate the fonts which has no option to use an already existing atlas for baking the new font into. What u mentioned is worth looking into. i didnt know you can intantiate a bimap font from a texture region. I refered to the [Bitmap contractor api](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/BitmapFont.html) and found 5 Bitmap Constructs that take TextureRegion:

Comment: (continued from last comment) @Tenfour04 Which one should i use? And please kindly explain each constructor. Write it as answer and i would mark it as accepted.

Comment: How does your method apply when using Skin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a constructor that takes a TextureRegion. For example, if your font and image were named `myFont.fnt` and `myFont.png`, you can put `myFont.png` in with the rest of your sprite source images and pack it into the texture atlas. Put the `.fnt` files in with the rest of your assets. Then after loading the texture atlas:

```
myFont = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("myFont.fnt"), myTextureAtlas.findRegion("myFont"));
```

To use it in a Skin, you'll want to add it to a Skin before loading the Json file:

```
skin = new Skin(); // instantiate blank skin
skin.add(myFont, "myFont");
skin.load(Gdx.files.internal("mySkin.json"));
```

The Json file can reference the font by the name you use when adding it to the skin.

Although, I'd highly advise using AssetManager for everything. In this case, your skin Json could define the font normally. The only extra step you need beyond loading everything to the asset manager the usual way would be to add a BitmapFontLoader.BitmapFontParameter that specifies the TextureAtlas that contains the region. The AssetManager will use this to determine that the BitmapFont is dependent on the atlas, so it will load them in the correct order.

```
BitmapFontLoader.BitmapFontParameter fontParam = new BitmapFontLoader.BitmapFontParameter(){{
    atlasName = "mySkin.pack";
}};
assetManager.load("myFont.fnt", BitmapFont.class, fontParam);
```

The atlas should be the same one the skin uses.